# Kotlin higher order function parameters: Passing subtypes

Tags: kotlin

I have run into a problem with function parameters in Kotlin. I will explain the issue with the help of some code.

I created a class hierarchy. When I pass a subtype into a function expecting a parent type, there is no issue.

```
open class A (val i: Int)
class B (val j: Int) : A(j)

fun f(x: A){
    print(x)
}

fun test_f(){
    f(A(1))
    f(B(1)) //no problem
}
```

I tried to mimic this with function parameters.

```
fun g(x: (A)->Int){
    print(x)
}

fun test_g(){
    val l1 = { a: A -> a.hashCode()}
    g(l1)

    val l2 = { b: B -> b.hashCode()}
    g(l2) //Error: Type mismatch. Required: (A)->Int, Found: (B)->Int
}
```

It seems that function type `(B) -> Int` is not a subtype of `(A) -> Int`. 
**What is the best way to address this?**

*My original problem* is to define a higher order function in `A.h` that takes a function  `z: (A) -> X` as parameter. And I want call `h` on an object of type `B` and pass a function `z: (B) -> X`.

**Update:**
I tried generics with upper bound, yet my issue is not solved. Please find code below:

```
// Using generics doesn't allow me to pass A.
open class A (val i: Int) {
    fun <M: A> g(x: (M)->Int){
        print(x(this)) // Error: Type mismatch. Expected: M, Found: A 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it using [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) and an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on a generic receiver. Deriving the extension function from your updated sample:

```
fun <T : A> T.g(x: (T)->Int){
    print(x(this))
}
```

This way it is ensured that the receiver and the first parameter type of the given function are the same, which is either an `A` or a subtype of it.

Comment: I tried that, but then it doesn't allow me to pass A. Check update for details.

Comment: @Neo updated the answer... basically showing how you can solve your updated sample with a generic function on a generic receiver...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Neat approach.

Comment: To help others looking at this: The important difference between the code I posted in my update and @Roland's answer is the "T.g" part, which allows the function to be an extension function for the generic type T.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is a conversion from function type `(B) -> Int` (*source*) to `(A) -> Int` (*target*). This is not a safe conversion.

Your source function `(B) -> Int` takes any instance which is a `B`, **but not necessarily an instance of type `A`**. More concretely, it cannot handle all arguments that are of type `A` but not of type `B`.

Imagine your classes look like this:

```
open class A
class B : A {
    fun onlyB() = 29
}
```

You can define a function

```
val fb: (B) -> Int = { it.onlyB() }
val fa: (A) -> Int = fb // ERROR
```

The function `fb` will not be able to operate on class `A`, since `A` does not have the `onlyB()` function. As a consequence, you're not allowed to convert it to a function type which takes `A` parameters.

---

This concept is called *contravariance*, meaning that input parameters can only be constrained by becoming **more concrete**, not more abstract. So, the opposite direction works:

```
val fa: (A) -> Int = { it.hashCode() }
val fb: (B) -> Int = fa // OK, every B is also an A
```

In contrast, for return values, the concept of *covariance* applies. This means that return values are allowed to become **more abstract**, but not more concrete:

```
val fInt: (B) -> Int = { it.onlyB() }
val fNum: (B) -> Number = fInt // OK, every Int is also a Number
```

These relations can be exploited in generic classes, using Kotlin's `in` (contravariance) and `out` (covariance) keywords -- see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Great answer — but is there a way to avoid any potential confusion between _in variance_ and _invariance_?  (E.g. _‘in’ variance_?)

Comment: I think better terms (also known in other languages) are _covariance/contravariance_ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))). Kotlin talks about _in/out_ in the context of [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), but not explicitly "in variance/out variance". I can edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Even better!  (Though there's now a typo in the last paragraph which rather spoils the effect… :)

Comment: And of course certain usages prevent either type of variance.